# Button inheritance onClick behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class which extends the Button-class. Why I do this, is because I want to use more than one label on the button.

The button works, and I've handled clicks on the label:

```
private void ClickOnLabel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClick(e);
}
```

Problem is, if I click and hold on a button the button reaches this "button pressed-state". And if I do the same on the label (which lies ontop of the button), it doesn't. The events that are using the method above is Click and DoubleClick. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I had to inheritate both MouseDown and MouseUp (along with Click) for get that behaviour.